# Executing shell commands from inside Pipeline Shared Library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

I'm writing a shared library that will get used in Pipelines.

```
class Deployer implements Serializable {
    def steps
    Deployer(steps) {
        this.steps = steps
    }
    
    def deploy(env) {
        // convert environment from steps to list
        def process = "ls -l".execute(envlist, null)
        process.consumeProcessOutput(output, error)
        process.waitFor()
        println output
        println error
    }
}
```

In the Jenkinsfile, I import the library, call the class and execute the deploy function inside a `script` section:

```
stage('mystep') {
    steps {
        script {
            def deployer = com.mypackage.HelmDeployer("test")
            deployer.deploy()
        }
    }
}
```

However, no output or errors are printed on the Console log.

Is it possible to execute stuff inside a shared library class? If so, how, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Jenkins only loads keywords from the vars folder, so you will need to create an adapter keyword inside the vars folder, in it you can initiate your class and return it - you can see this in the `virtualenv` keyword in the [following example](https://github.com/Ableton/python-pipeline-utils/tree/master/vars).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but not really an obvious solution. Every call that is usually done in the Jenkinsfile but was moved to the shared-library needs to reference the `steps` object you passed.

You can also reference the Jenkins environment by calling `steps.env`.

I will give you a short example:

```
class Deployer implements Serializable {
   def steps
   Deployer(steps) {
      this.steps = steps
   }

    def callMe() {
        // Always call the steps object
        steps.echo("Test")
        steps.echo("${steps.env.BRANCH_NAME}")
        steps.sh("ls -al")

        // Your command could look something like this:
        // def process = steps.sh(script: "ls -l", returnStdout: true).execute(steps.env, null)
        ...
    }
}
```

You also have to import the object of the shared library and create an instance of it. Define the following outside of your Pipeline.

```
import com.mypackage.Deployer // path is relative to your src/ folder of the shared library
def deployer = new Deployer(this) // 'this' references to the step object of the Jenkins
```

Then you can call it in your pipeline as the following:

```
... script { deployer.test() } ...
```